# How use dynamoose in aws lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

Actually, I am new to AWS Lambda functions and Amazon DynamoDB,
so I could not find a way to create a table with a Dynamoose schema and create CRUD operation with it.

I am familiar with mongoose and I read that Dynamoose is inspired by it.

So, can anybody tell me how to create CRUD operations in Lambda by using Dynamoose schema?

Comment: The same way you would create the CRUD operations without lambda. Difference is that you create one crud operation per lambda function/API endpoint and that you need to create appropriate lambda execution role. Also, you will need to bundle the dependencies with the function.

Comment: Thanks @MatusDubrava for the reply.
Actually, I made a schema method to add object in dynamo db. But getting this error: 
**  "errorMessage": "2020-08-06T06:04:36.091Z 69b63932-6d6e-40c1-8cfa-b78a6ad6f033 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"**

my schema: 
const tableSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        hashKey: true,
    },
    name: String
}
});
// my method.
const newData = await tableSchema.create({
                    id: uuid.v4(),
                    name: 'tanuj'
                });

Comment: If you have a specific issue then I would suggest posting it as new question since the original one is a bit vague. Feel free to post the URL of the new question here and I can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way, you would create the CRUD operations without the lambda. The difference is that you create one crud operation per lambda function/API endpoint and that you need to create an appropriate lambda execution role. Also, you will need to bundle the dependencies with the function.